# JQuery Tooltip and Scrollable Fix

Tags: jquery

I have set up the navigation on my site using a scrollable div created with Flowplayer's JQuery tools. I also want to add a tooltip to the individual images within the scrollable div. The problem is the tooltip needs to appear outside of the div. I can adjust the height of the div so you can see the tooltip, but the tooltip is still constrained inside another div. Here is the link to my code.

http://staging.asla.org/sustainablesites/TestAGAIN.html

Is there a way to make this tooltip (div) appear out of it's containing divs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your issue. You could do a couple things though:

1. Position the DIV with CSS (combination of position:absolute and z-index).
2. Place Markup for the DIV outside of the Container to begin with, and change its contents depending which item you're mousing over.